# Can i add URL as a field in Azure Devops work items via manually or through automation

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

Can I add URL as a field in Azure DevOps work items via manually or through automation and that can be editable?

Expecting a new field type to add a URL to open a URL in a single click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Expecting a new field type to add a URL to open a URL in a single click

I am afraid that there is no built-in field type can meet your requirements.

To meet your requirement, you can use this extension: [Clickable Links](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MarkHawkes.clickable-link-control-extension).

Here are the steps:

Step1: Create a normal string type field in work item(Organization Settings -> Process).

Step2: Click the option:  **Add custom control** and select the normal string type field.

[image]

[image]

It will generate a new URL type field with the same name.

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks Kevin, that worked. Appreciated your quick response.